# Cocos2d 2.0 error xcode 5.2

Tags: iphone, for-loop, cocos2d-iphone, xcode4.5, cgrect

```
for (CCSprite *body in bodyArray) {
    if (CGRectIntersectsRect(snakeHead.boundingBox, body.boundingBox)) {
        [self unscheduleUpdate];
        [self gameOver];
    }
}
```

This is my code which worked perfectly on xcode4.2 osx 10.6.8,
but when I HAD to upgrade to xcode 4.5 this gives me a warning "Local declaration of 'body' hides instance variable"
I have no single clue what this means and I have searched for the problem but haven't found any soution.
Does anyone here understand this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an instance variable named `body` in your `.h` file. You have used the same name on the following line too 
`for (CCSprite *body in bodyArray)`.

So this warning message means that instance variable `body` declared in `.h` file will not used within the scope of your `for` loop

Comment: Thank you, you have made me into a smarter person.